# Python compare two lists, add specific string to list if substring is in main list

Tags: python, list, selenium

I have a python bot which scrapes a website for data. Once it has the data it's filtered and the names are read clearly; this is list 1. Then, in list 2, I have strings of set names and I'm trying to compare list 2 to list 1 to see if list 1 contains one of any of the strings from list 2, and if it does, list 1 will have a string inserted into it showing that it contains a string from list 2. This is my loop:

```
for x in boss_bots:
    for index, y in enumerate(new_bots):
        if x in y[index]:
            new_bots.insert(index, 'Boss Bot')
```

Here is the rest of the code

```
from selenium import webdriver
from time import sleep

boss_bots = ['Flunky', 'Pencil Pusher', 'Yesman', 'Micro manager', 'Downsizer', 'Head Hunter', 'Corporate Raider',
             'The Big Cheese']
cash_bots = ['Short Change', 'Penny Pincher', 'Tightwad', 'Bean Counter', 'Number Cruncher', 'Money Bags', 'Loan Shark',
             'Robber Baron']
sell_bots = ['Cold Caller', 'Telemarketer', 'Name Dropper', 'Glad Hander', 'Mover & Shaker', 'Two-Face', 'The Mingler',
             'Mr. Hollywood']
law_bots = ['Bottom Feeder', 'Blood sucker', 'Double Talker', 'Ambulance Chaser', 'Back Stabber', 'Spin Doctor',
            'Legal Eagle', 'Big Wig']


def format_box(bots):
    new_bots = []
    for string in bots:
        new_bot = string.replace('', ' ')
        new_bots.append(new_bot)
    return new_bots


def print_bots(bots):
    for i in bots:
        print(i)
        print()


def get_all_info():
    driver = webdriver.Chrome()
    driver.get("https://toonhq.org/invasions/")
    sleep(2)
    bots = driver.find_elements_by_class_name('media-body')
    info = [name.text for name in bots if name.text != '']
    new_bots = format_box(info)

    t = 0
    """    for index, (x, y) in enumerate(zip(boss_bots, info)):
        if x == y:
            new_bots.insert(index, 'Boss Bot')"""

    for x in boss_bots:
        for index, y in enumerate(new_bots):
            #print('Boss bots: ' + x + 'index: ' + str(index) + 'Bot list: ' + y)
            if x in y[index]:
                new_bots.insert(index, 'Boss Bot')

    print_bots(new_bots)
    driver.close()
    return info


get_all_info()
```

Comment: Please excuse me. What is your question?

Comment: When I run my program, it scrapes information off of a website. This information is loaded into a list. Once it's done scraping, it then compares this list (list 1) with another list (list 2) which is the boss_bots list at the top. If list 1 contains any of the names from list 2, then I want list 1 to insert the string 'Boss bot' at the specific index where the text matches.

Comment: Sorry. I don't follow you. To keep it easier for you to get more help, I'm going to delete my post.

Comment: I'm going to try integrating your solution.

Comment: Sure. Go for it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for s in newbots:
    if s in bossbots:
        s = s+'bossbot'
    else:
        continue


# Another possible method with list comprehension.
[s+'bossbot' for s in newbots if s in bossbots]
```

Also another way of filtering blank space from your list. This would replace format_box.

```
newbots = list(filter(newbots, None))
```

Comment: I just solved it actually, but my solution is similar to your first one:

`for s in sell_bots:

        for index, n in enumerate(new_bots):

            #print('Boss bots: ' + x + 'index: ' + str(index) + 'Bot list: ' + y)

            if s in n:

                new_bots.insert(index, 'Sell Bot')`

Comment: cool thanks for the accept if you want edit the answer . was the key to use enumerate to fetch the index?

Comment: What I was trying to do was insert a string into an index that was already set. For some reason I thought that would work since I'm coming from C++ and I guess arrays and lists work differently. I just wan't sure what the syntax was to add a string to an already set string in the list so the key was doing the + 'boss bots' to the index that passes the 'in' check.

Answer (score 0):

Hope I got your problem right. If you do want to replace list 1 items with 'Boss Bot' string if item in list one matches the items in list 2. For this, you can use list indexes

`for i in range(len(new_bots)) :

         if(new_bots[i] in boss_bots) :
              new_bots[i] = 'Boss Bot'`

Comment: Close, I needed to add the 'Boss Bot' to the end of the string in that certain index in new_bots. But thanks for the response.